# Grub and Ubuntu disappeared after fastboot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grub-legacy

I had Ubuntu 20.4 installed alongside Windows 10 (legacy mode) I have an SSD and HDD
and had ubuntu installed on the SSD as Windows was there too.

I don't know exactly what happened but I think my laptop ran out of battery overnight and when I booted it up there was grub rescue mode

I tried to fix it and it did but now it boots to windows directly and no grub or ubuntu.
Also tried doing live boot from USB and having boot repair but no luck
and with windows cmd but no luck either

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Windows 10 updates are know to turn fast start up back on. Make sure it is off before running report. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation